# Geocoding many addresses - CLGeocoder

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

I need to geocode a ton of addresses with CLGeocoder, *not* the Google API.

My problem is that my code is only adding an annotation for the first address in the array below. However, the function gets called an appropriate number of times - **the block just runs for the first address after the function has been called for ALL of the addresses:**

```
- (void)mapPoints {
    NSString *foo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"names%d", self.indexOfSchool] ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *description = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:foo];
    NSString *bar = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d1", self.indexOfSchool] ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *details = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:bar];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d0", self.indexOfSchool] ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *addresses = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.saved = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int q = 0; q < addresses.count; q+= 20) {
        [self annotate:[addresses objectAtIndex:q] detail:[details objectAtIndex:q] andDesc:[description objectAtIndex:q]];
    }
}

see updated annotate: method below...
```

Here are how my logs appear:

```
here
here
here
here
.
..
...
....
<MKPointAnnotation: 0x16fc12e0>
```

Therefore, although the function is being called with the loop, the block is not running for any results other than the first.

I know my addresses are good. This does not work for any number (>1) of calls to the function.
The `+= 20` in the loop has nothing to do with only one point being plotted: this does not work for `++` either (there are also around 200 results).

I'm fairly new to blocks, so hopefully this is an easy fix. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Doing this instead:

```
- (void)annotate:(NSString *)address detail:(NSString *)detail andDesc:(NSString *)description {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error) {
                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                     MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                     point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                     point.title = description;
                     point.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ miles from origin", detail];
                     MKCoordinateRegion region = self.directionsView.region;
                     region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];
                     region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                     region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                     [self.directionsView addAnnotation:point];
                     NSLog(@"%@", point);
                     [self.directionsView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                 }
             }
 ];
    [self.saved addObject:geocoder];
    NSLog(@"%@", geocoder);
}
```

... still pulls up a blank map with no annotations -- not even the first. The geocoder array has a different memory address upon each call to the function, so that piece appears to be working.

Comment: I think you should go with semaphores in GCD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling the geocodeAddressString a few times in a row, but apple's docs say

> After initiating a forward-geocoding request, do not attempt to
>   initiate another forward- or reverse-geocoding request.

So I think what is happening is either the current request is cancelled when you make a new one, or all new requests are ignored if one is already in progress.

As a workaround you could geocode one point, and then geocode the next point in the completion block or create multiple instances of the geocoder

Comment: you need to retain a reference to the new geocoder instance, or it will be dealloced before the completion block is called

Comment: I'm using ARC - no retaining

Comment: you still need to retain it. adding it to an array would be the simplest way

Comment: Ok. I'm missing something: adding it to an array and doing what then?

Comment: nothing, just calling the geocode method the same as you do now. adding it to the array retains it so it doesn't get dealloced at the end of the method

Comment: hmm. Adding `[self.saved addObject:geocoder];` in my annotate: method after the block does nothing.

Comment: can you update your code? are any completion blocks being called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40751/discussion-between-9fermat-and-wattson12)

Answer (score 3):

Each `CLGeocoder` object can only process one request at a time. Try creating a new `CLGeocoder` object inside your `annotate` method instead of reusing a single object stored in a property. As long as you have ARC enabled, you should be okay.

Note that Apple may place restrictions on the number of simultaneous requests you send to their servers, so you may need to limit the number of outstanding requests if you're doing a large number of them.

Comment: @9fermat Could you post the entire updated `annotate` method? You'd see that behavior if you're still trying to use `self.geocoder` instead of `geocoder`. Also, what do you mean by "instance instead of property"?

Comment: What I mean is that I'm not using `self.geocoder`, rather just `geocoder` — the instance, not the property.

Comment: @9fermat Okay, please post the entire updated method anyway. :-)

Comment: This is the true answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can have only **one geocoding request running at a time** regardless of how many instances of `CLGeocoder` you have. You will have to start another request from withing the completion block of the previous one.

Also, take into account, that geocoding too many addresses in a short time will reach its internal limit. In my experiments, after ~50 requests (one after another) the framework refused to process new requests for next ~60 seconds.

Comment: How would you start a new request inside the previous one?

Comment: @9fermat I had the array of addresses as a property and started it all by calling `[self geocodeAddressAtIndex:0];`. Then in the completion block of geocoder I just called recursively the same method with incremented index: `[self geocodeAddressAtIndex:(i + 1)];`

Answer (score -2):

This is a Xamarin pseudo-code but it should work the same in native as I had to convert to C# in the first place:

```
forloop()
{
    var geocoder = new CLGeocoder();
    var placemarks = await geocoder.GeocodeAddressAsync(address);
}
```